# how do i show paginate links when i have called it from another function laravel

Tags: laravel, function, eloquent, pagination

I have this function from where i call another function in services. I have paginated in that function. now the thing is the number of data is as I have decaled but I can't just use links in view.

```
function example (){
    $a = $this->exampleService->paginationfunction($all,12);
    return view->(['a'=>$a])
}
```

in example service:

```
function paginationfunction($all,$paginate){
    $x = Users::where('address',$all->name);
    return $x->paginate($paginate);
}
```

now in view i have used `$a->links()` which shows error of

> Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::links does not exist.

Comment: Where is `$all` being set in your `example` function? Are you certain `view->('a'=>$a)` is correct? Have you tried _not_ using `->get()` before you paginate?

Comment: my bad. i haven't used get in my code though